# How to tag API calls to Amazon Rekognition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition, aws-sdk-java

Each of my customers pays for its part of my total AWS costs. Therefore, I tagged all my resources (EC2, EBS, S3, ...) and I created an [AWS Cost and Usage Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/what-is-cur.html) for each of my customer. But I couldn't find a way to tag API calls to Amazon Rekognition.

**Code**

```java
AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.defaultClient();

S3Object s3Object = new S3Object().withBucket(bucketName).withName(fileName);
DetectModerationLabelsRequest request = new DetectModerationLabelsRequest()
                .withImage(new Image().withS3Object(s3Object))
                .withMinConfidence(0F);
DetectModerationLabelsResult result = rekognitionClient.detectModerationLabels(request);
```

**Reasearch**

I read JavaDoc for [`DetectModerationLabelsRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rekognition/model/DetectModerationLabelsRequest.html), [`AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rekognition/AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.html) and [`ClientConfiguration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html), but I couldn't find anything about tagging.

**Question**

How can I tag my API calls to Amazon Rekognition?